# How can I decrease sparse matrix columns size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm applying the bag-of-words algorithm to a bunch of documents and, after the data preprocessing I still have a sparse matrix of 6723 rows and 8356 columns. These rows have a lot of zeros becouse of the size of the vocabulary, so how can I reduce the quantity of columns?

Comment: Look up dimensionality reduction, tf-idf, countvectorizer, etc.

Comment: what data structure are you using the hold the info? a dataframe?

Comment: An numpy.array object.

Comment: then take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html